# why alert function not show index of each one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create one object named "Ball". 
after document load, script will create 12 instance of object and insert so many element li to

```
<ul></ul>
```

my purpose is that when click ball, it show index of ball.
for exmaple: click No 3 ball,  it show 3.
but when i click each ball, it always show 12.

sorry, i cannot upload snapshot for html document, since i am new guy here.

```
function Ball(idx, parent, libra) {
    this.idx = idx;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.libra = libra;
    this.init();
}

Ball.r = 30;

Ball.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        var _html = $("<li><div class='ball'><span>" + this.idx + "</span></div></li>"),
        pos
        _this = this;
        this.parent.append(_html);
        this.html = _html.find(".ball");
        this.html.css({
            height: Ball.r * 2 + "px",
            width: Ball.r * 2 + "px",
            lineHeight: Ball.r * 2 + "px"
        });
        pos = this.html.position()
        this.html.css({
            left: pos.left + "px",
            top: pos.top + "px",
            position: "absolute"
         });
         this.html.mousedown(function() {alert(_this.idx)});
    }
};


$("document").ready(function() {
    var parent = $("#balls ul"),
    libra = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        new Ball(i, parent, libra)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma so `_this` is global.

```
    var _html = $("<li><div class='ball'><span>" + this.idx + "</span></div></li>"),
    pos  <--- missing comma here
    _this = this;
```

Since it is global, you are getting the value of the last Ball created.

The solution:

Add the missing comma.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the element that user clicked on. That means that you need to listen for click events on the Ball html that you output. Your Ball object should look like this:

```
Ball.prototype = {
init: function() {
    var _html = $("<li><div class='ball'><span>" + this.idx + "</span></div></li>"),
    pos;
    _this = this;
    this.parent.append(_html);
    this.html = _html.find(".ball");
    this.html.css({
        height: Ball.r * 2 + "px",
        width: Ball.r * 2 + "px",
        lineHeight: Ball.r * 2 + "px"
    });
    pos = this.html.position()
    this.html.css({
        left: pos.left + "px",
        top: pos.top + "px",
        position: "absolute"
     });

     $(_html).on("click", function(e) {
         alert(e.currentTarget.textContent);
     });

     //this.html.mousedown(function() {alert(_this.idx)});
}
```

};

Notice the line that I commented and the click event function that I attached to the html of your Ball li.

Read more about events and event propagation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Comment: You made _this global in your code. Hence the poster's original problem.

Comment: Yes it did, the missing comma made the _this global, hence why the _this pointed to the last instance. Do you want a working demo? In your code above, you made _this global since there is no var in front of it. It does not effect you since you never use it.